# Using getter methods for generated values. Good or bad?

Tags: java, methods, wicket, el, getter

Ok I know I can do this because I've seen it work before.

Basically, I make a getter method in one of my classes such a that the method doesn't have an associated class variable.

For example

```
@Entity
public class Customer implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer customerID;

@NaturalId
private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "customerID", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<CustomerAddress> customerAddressList;
.
.
.
public CustomerAddress getMainAddress(){
    //Calculations to retrieve the customer's main/default/primary address
    //from the List, customerAddressList.
}
```

While I haven't tried this in Thymeleaf (but intend to do so soon), I do know in Wicket I can use property expressions to access the main address of a customer (which I think is interesting because there is no variable called `mainAddress`in the Customer class).

That being said, **is this use of getters is considered an acceptable practice**?

Comment: If you did not do this, what would you do?

Comment: I just found my answer in a different question http://stackoverflow.com/q/9689081/1815513