# Should we have java getter for bean without actual property behind it?

Tags: java, javabeans, getter, struts-1

Is it a good practice to have getter method for a property for which actual property in not defined inside a bean. For example let's say I have a bean class like below:
Website Bean:

```
public class Website
{
    private string name;

    public string getName() {
     return name;
    }

    public string getUrl() {
      return "http://" + name + "-env.organization.com";
    }   
}
```

And lets say if I am working on struts the using this class as follows :
Index.jsp:

```
        <logic:present name="Website" property="url">
            <li><a href="<bean:write name="Website" property="url"/>" class="webAdress" target="_blank"><bean:write name="exhibitor" property="url"/></a></li>
        </logic:present>
```

So my question is: 
Is is a good practice to use **url** like this in jsp file while we don't have any property binding behind it. Do we see any issues in this or its perfectly fine to use like this ?

edit: changed return type to string of getUrl()

Comment: The important point about *beans* is that they have methods with names starting with `get` anything else is implementation detail...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java getter for non-existent attribute of class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689081/java-getter-for-non-existent-attribute-of-class)

Comment: getUrl() method returns a String, not an int, right? Anyways, I don't see an issue with having a getter for a non-existent attribute, especially if the value does not change with new instances

Comment: What's returned is irrelevant, e.g., `getFullName()` could return a value calculated from first and last name properties. It's perfectly reasonable (and expected).

Comment: @AdamsonJeremiah: yes return type is string. I changed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's perfectly OK to have the `getUrl()` method.

To the outside world, your Website class has a property named `url`, no matter how the class answers questions for this property - that's private internals of your class. Bean properties are not at all restricted to just pass a field value.

Things might become a little more complex if you were to implement a `setUrl()` method, as your callers expect the `getUrl()` method to return the value they stored with `setUrl()`.

Comment: thanks all for the reply. I guess it makes sense to have getter without property.